# C#7 - throw как выражение в тернарном операторе

Tags: c#

В версии C#7 и выше мы можем бросать исключения в одной из веток тернарного оператора:

```
var a = 1 < 2 ? "true" : throw new Exception();
```

почему мы не можем таким же образом пробросить пойманное исключение дальше?

Например:

```
try
{
    var er = 1/0;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var a = ex.InnerException == null ? ex.Message : throw;
}
```

Я так понимаю, что в стандартном использовании `throw` используется некий неявный «контекст» инструкции `try-catch`, откуда и достаётся информация об отловленном исключении. Почему не используется тот же «контекст» в случае с тернарным оператором?

Аналогично, интересует ситуация и с *null-coalescing* оператором - `??`.

---

Вариант с явным указанием пойманного исключения в качестве аргумента для `throw` не годится - работать будет, но в этом случае стек-трейс будет утерян.

```
try
{
    var er = 1/0;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var a = ex.InnerException == null ? ex.Message : throw ex;
}
```

Comment: Я видимо что-то не понимаю..  зачем нужно ловить ошибку, а потом заново его выбрасывать?

Comment: @SultanovShamil, например чтобы залогировать

Comment: @Grundy выглядит костыльненько имхо, выброс исключений не самая быстрая операция всё-таки

Comment: @SultanovShamil, так и происходит она в _исключительных случаях_.

Comment: Как по мне, вы пытаетесь добавить дополнительную логику там, где она не требуется. И мне кажется логичным решение не позволять делать так, как вы хотите. Если ловится исключение - это значит, что в данном участке кода произошла ошибка, которая может повлиять на дальнешее выполнение программы и тут два пути: либо всё пропало окончательно, либо программа может выполняться дальше, даже если в предыдущем участке кода были проблемы. В первом случае, вы просто пробрасываете дальше исключение: `catch (Exception ex) { throw; }`. Во втором же вы можете использовать тот же синглтон для логирования.

Comment: throw ex; и  throw; компилятся в разные инструкции IL  throw и rethrow соответственно. При этом rethrow можно использовать только в блоке catch. Конструкции такие как object Method() { throw new Exception(); } были изначально доступны, и думаю возможность раскрыть их в выражениях не стоило больших затрат для разработчиков компилятора. В случае rethrow чтобы добавить такую возможность, нужно дополнительно на этапе синтаксического анализа выражения колхозить доп правила: в блоке catch оно или нет  и т.д. И думаю с этим просто не стали заморачиваться, профит сомнительный...

Comment: Я наверное один не понимаю зачем вам тернарный оператор в блоке `catch`... Можете объяснить зачем он вам? В вашем примере вы не используете переменную `a`, значение которой определяете через данный оператор.

Comment: @Anamnian **ЭТО. ПРОСТО. ПРИМЕР.** для иллюстрации. вопрос про механизм работы оператора `throw`. это непонятно из текста вопроса?

Answer (score 8):

Судя по обсуждению [на гитхабе](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/5143), о таком варианте просто не подумали.

Однако, в языке есть другая конструкция который подойдет в подобных случаях:

```
try
{
    var er = 1/0;
}
catch (Exception ex) when (ex.InnerException == null)
{
    var a = ex.Message;
}
```

Ведь если исключение не ловить - то не придется его кидать обратно.

Comment: у меня нет задачи ) это просто примеры к вопросу, меня больше интересует механизм неявной передачи исключения во `throw`. где можно про это почитать?

Comment: объективно, это - не ответ

Comment: @Anatol, а в чем суть вопроса-то? Почему не работает приведенный код? – Это баг/недоработка в компиляторе.

Comment: @АндрейNOP - ну допустим это понятно, *Я так понимаю, что в стандартном использовании throw используется некий неявный «контекст» инструкции try-catch, откуда и достаётся информация об отловленном исключении. Почему не используется тот же «контекст» в случае с тернарным оператором?* - с этим что?

Comment: @Anatol *баг/недоработка в компиляторе*

Comment: @Anatol цитирую: *"о таком варианте просто не подумали"*. Какие еще причины вам нужны?

Comment: @PavelMayorov это годно для комментария. Если уж это принимать как ответ, то не мешало бы разбавить подробностями. Нет? Конструкция из второй части ответа к вопросу отношение имеет весьма косвенное

Comment: @Anatol какого рода комментариев вы ждете?

Comment: @Anatol, Вам ответили что сделать как вы хотите нельзя, вам ответили почему нельзя, и вам ответили как сделать можно. Что вы ещё ждёте?

Answer (score 0):

Если проблема именно в сохранении предыдущего стектрейса в throw ex и записи в одну строчку, то можно начудить как-нибудь так:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

public static class ExceptionHelper
{
    public static Exception PreserveStackTrace(this Exception e)
    {
        var streamingContext = new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.CrossAppDomain);
        var objectManager = new ObjectManager(null, streamingContext);
        var serializationInfo = new SerializationInfo(e.GetType(), new FormatterConverter());

        e.GetObjectData(serializationInfo, streamingContext);
        objectManager.RegisterObject(e, 1, serializationInfo);
        objectManager.DoFixups();
        return e;
    }

    public static object Throw(this Exception ex) => throw ex;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            try
            {
                throw new Exception("exception");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.PreserveStackTrace();
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                var a = ex.InnerException != null ? ex.Message : ex.PreserveStackTrace().Throw();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Но на самом деле, какая-то мышиная возня, не совсем понятно чем предыдущий ответ не устраивает.

Comment: ТС как раз написал в комментариях к предыдущему ответу, что его не интересует **как разрешить** подобную задачу, его интересует лишь **механизм** работы указанной конструкции

Comment: А-а-а! Ну зачем сразу сериализация-то?.. Чем прогон через `ExceptionDispatchInfo` не вариант?